# How to replace -- More -- in more command (batch)

Tags: command-line, batch, user-interface, more

The `more.com` command in batch scripting is easy enough for people used to it.

```
 Space  Display next page.

Return Display next line.

 Q  Quit.

... Etc...
```

But to the inexperienced user this is not self explanatory. Therefor I'm wondering if it is possible to replace the text the more command outputs when waiting for user input.

From this:

```
-- More --
```

To maybe something like this:

```
Press  Space  to display next page | Return to display next line |  Q  to quit.
```

Comment: for inexperienced users they should use a GUI instead. Most people won't be willing to read text in the console if they're not familiar with any commands. And cmd's capability is very limited, you should use powershell instead, if this is ever possible. For example if `more` prints `-- More --` in stderr then in powershell you can redirect stderr and replace the string using with a named pipe or `tee`, but that's impossible in cmd